# Syntax error postgreSQL at idx()

Tags: linux, python-2.7, postgresql

I am trying to execute a postgresql query, but getting a syntax error. The query is:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE smaller_coverage "
      "AS (SELECT donor_id, block_id, "
      " sorted_ids[(:idx(sorted_ids, block_id) - 1)]"
      "      AS smaller_ids "
      " FROM plural_block INNER JOIN covered_blocks "
      " USING (donor_id))")
```

The error is at :idx.
Can someone please rectify the code and also explain it.
Thanks

Comment: :idx  should be a bind variable.. and bind variables aren't allowed to be functions or funciton names which this appears to be. What are you trying to accomplish and why is this function name variable?

Comment: Sorry, I dont have much idea about postgresql. The query seems to be running fine when ':' is removed. Will this cause any problem with the final output?

Comment: : in postgresql is kinda like "$" in php.. it's a marker for a variable. Removing it means you're running a function called "idx".. if such a function exists and that's what you want to run, then yeah, the : should be removed.
-- edit: For posterity, I do know that the explanation about : is a gross oversimplification.

Comment: okk i got it..thank you so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

: in postgresql is kinda like "$" in php.. it's a marker for a variable. Removing it means you're running a function called "idx".. if such a function exists and that's what you want to run, then yeah, the : should be removed. -- edit: For posterity, I do know that the explanation about : is a gross oversimplification.

In short, instead of :idx, use the function name you wish to call.